# URL and phpmyadmin auto increments

Tags: php, mysql, security, phpmyadmin

I am looking for the best way to approach this issues that I am having and I have been looking for a way to try and solves it.

I have a database table called `products` and in this table I have all my products in its like shoes, clothes, caps, etc

I have a single page which I used to echo everything into its based on the product `ID` the code I am using looks like this

```
<a href="product.php?ID=<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>">View</a>
```

the url looks like this

```
http://www.example.x10.mx/product.php?ID=1
```

The issues is that someone can just change `ID` to 2 or 3 or 4.... which shouldn't happen. I don't know if the issue is that it is not using a paid domain or its just on x10hosting.

**Problem**

I want to provide uses from changing the `ID` in the url to whatever random number they want and can someone please show me how this can be done.

**Another Question**
Is they a way phpMyadmin can generate a mixture of random letters and numbers because that is the only way I thought of to solve my problem

Thanks

Comment: Why should they not be able to edit the ID themselves? How will you ensure the the "code" is always the same to preserve bookmarks and what not, or should this not be referenceable at all?

Comment: @prodigitalson the thing is the way i design the product.php and itemview.php page is that the both echo the ID so if i change the ID to 2 while I was on itemview.php page it will show things related to that ID which shouldn't be display on itemview.php and the same related to many other products

Comment: As long as you're not depending on them having the same ID for security or validation, it shouldn't be a problem. They'll get mixed up displays, but it's their own fault. They shouldn't do that and expect to get reasonable output, and you shouldn't worry about it.

Comment: You shouldn't use anything in the URL for security. Your database should state which users have access to which product IDs, and the server scripts should check the ID against this when it receives the request.

Comment: @Luffy: i agree with Bumar, i think youre imposing an unnecessary requirement on yourself. Also what you are describing from what I am abel to discern from your naming anyway, doesnt make much sense. They are two different views, so either they are independent which then makes this situation moot, or they are both based off of the entity and id (product/item).

Comment: @prodigitalson sorry to make you confuse but they is nothing to be really confuse about. For an example the cap, shoe uses the product.php page and the gloves, shirts uses the itemview.php pages both pages uses the product ID (`ID`) when you click on view. Hope that makes sense

Comment: also if u look at the links below skrilled answer. You can see that even though you change and letter in the url you will not be redirect but you will still be in the same page

Answer (score -1):

I had to approach an issue similar to this when doing our commerce system at work. The way we handled it was to provide a hash of the values that users have in their query..

If you for encrypt the query string against a salt and make your urls /product.php?id=1&hash=ajk23j4aksdljfklasdjf2345j - Then on product.php verify that the hash matches up correctly. If the hashes do not match up it means the user has changed something.

Comment: Let's say for example I have the url: http://www.website.com/script.php?id=5&subid=10 - I would take the id=5&subid=10 and create an encrypted string of that against a salt. The link would be appended with that hash: http://www.website.com/script.php?id=5&subid=10&hash=hashhere - then you would just ensure that encrypted/hashed string that is calculated matches up with what is in the query string

Comment: If you are trying to be simple and don't need advanced security, you could even just do something like this: $hash = md5(md5($id)); I highly doubt your average user will calculate out what the double md5 hash of your ID is.. Then just on the script itself verify that $_GET['hash'] == md5(md5($_GET['id']));

Comment: is they a guide somewhere i can follow or have an idea how to do your first answer please?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php - that's one example. there's lots of ways to create hashes or encrypted strings, the key is you're hashing the query string not a password, and validating the hash will be basically the same method that you created the hash in the first place (without the hash=X part of the query string)

Comment: who disliked this answer and why?

Answer (score -1):

This isn't really an answer but I felt compelled to post here because of what I feel is a poor app design situation.

From the comment thread on the main question:

> sorry to make you confuse but they is nothing to be really confuse about. For an example the cap, shoe uses the product.php page and the gloves, shirts uses the itemview.php pages both pages uses the product ID (ID) when you click on view. Hope that makes sense

It still doesn't make sense. All of these things you mention are in fact products. Just different type of products. In any sane design they will all use the same URL format. The logic to do things based on the type of product belongs in whatever you are using as a controller - in your case I assume the .php page in the URL. You need only one of these. From there you can do different things.

Example in the most basic sense:

```
// This is product.php

if(!isset($_GET['id'])) {
  // 404 or some other error
}

$product = get_item_by_id($_GET['id']);

if(!$product) {
   // 404 or other error
}

switch($product['type']) {
    case 'cap':
    case 'shoes':
       // for cap and shoes use the product_view template
       include 'product_view.php';
       break;

    case 'gloves':
    case 'shirts':
        // for gloves and shirts use the item_view template
       include 'item_view.php';
       break;

    default:
       // otherwise use the default product view template
       include 'default_view.php';
   
}

// anything else you need to do that isn't done in the view specific file
```

Now that all assumes these are specific products, but your examples sound more like categories. Normally you would have a separate page for categories that did much the same thing as the product but outputted a "collection" of product entities in some visual fashion.

Comment: `'type'` will be a table name in the database? also will this code be ideal for the page which I am displaying all my products in?

Comment: `type` would be a column name on the `product` table using my example above. Personally i wouldnt use type i would use a separate field like `view` or `template` and put name in there that would map to `the_name.php`. This allows you to change the template that outputs things separately from the actual type of product which will most likely have semantic significance.

Comment: If you are displaying ALL your products on one page why would you have had both `product.php` and `itemview.php` in the first place? The fact that you had two pages implies that there are at least 2 distinct types of items (at least from a look-and-feel perspective) and that you wanted to display them separately...

Comment: Sorry I don't fully understand from the `"personally..."`. Are you trying to say that I should have a column name`view` or `template` and in that column I should have a like to a php page called `the_name.php` and then assign this name to all the items that are in the shoes category and cap and then have a different php page link to some of the other products

Comment: I have a different page which displays only shoes and hats. so it will be like `www.itemviw.php?ID=5` BUT IF u change the `ID` to 1 it will display a glove because I have a blue glove in the product which as an `ID` of `1`